# Add Tomcat support to existing Netbeans Scala project

Tags: web-applications, scala, tomcat, netbeans

I have a Scala project and I now want Netbeans to integrate it with Tomcat. Right now I am manually copying the files into Tomcat directory (via build.xml). Is there any way where I can configure Netbeans to recognize it as a web-application and automatically deploy it on run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could configure it as a maven project and use the maven tomcat plugin. Netbeans can handle maven and maven can handle tomcat.

I develop in scala/lift/netbeans myself and ended up using [sbt](http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/)'s continuous compilation feature. That is quite handy because you can configure it to automatically redeploy if you change sources and it does that within 2 seconds or so. But its not integrated into netbeans or anything (allthough you can of course configure Netbeans to call sbt).